# Divide a string in python using specific substring

Tags: python, string

I have a txt file with some information regarding bounding boxes in an image. I would like to open that txt file automatically read the information and crop image using coordinates of the bounding box. Text file has the following format:

```
folder\file_0001.jpg 75 165 87 177 106.750000 108.250000 143.750000 108.750000 131.250000 127.250000 106.250000 155.250000 142.750000 155.250000
folder\file_0002.jpg 86 162 93 169 104.750000 110.750000 145.750000 114.250000 126.250000 139.750000 104.250000 155.250000 139.250000 159.750000
```

The useful bounding boxes coordinates are the first 4 integer after the file name. How can I separate those values and use it for cropping my images in python?

Comment: So what have you tried? Have you looked at string.split() ?

Comment: Anything (code) you have tried so far? While this has a relatively easy answer, people at StackOverflow will generally not write code for you.

Comment: Ok my issue is how to keep the first 4 integer values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `split` to split the string on spaces, then slice the returned list to get the elements out that you are interested in.

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        coords = line.split()[1:5]  # Use slicing to get the 2nd through 5th elements
```